# Examples of long-polling in ASP.NET combined with WCF service monitoring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services, long-polling

We have a number of Windows services running in our system (built in C#).  We use WCF to communicate with them and control them, since WCF offers very convenient communication with these processes.

Right now in our Windows GUI for managing, monitoring and troubleshooting the services, we simply register callbacks and receive notifications when a message is available from the service.  Obviously this application is stateful and WCF provides the ability for the local delegate to be called when the maintained connection to the service indicates.

In our web application which users actually use, we'd like to use long-polling to have a status area on the web page (iframe, AJAX, whatever) which shows any issues which the services are reporting.  We'd like to use a long-polling or other technique which minimizes actual polling on the network.

The problem we are running up against is that we need something to make the long-polling HTTP request against which will somehow always be running in IIS and which itself can be WCF-connected to our services and which can convert the event/delegate-based WCF response into a blocking-style long-poll response.  It feels like a chicken-and-egg situation that some component in our system is always going to be in a loop, polling - and that's exactly what we are trying to avoid.

Does anyone have an example of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your services present with WCF, why not simply consume the WCF services with javsacript?  Then you remove your IIS servers from the equation completely.  if a user wants to see what the services are doing then they can retrieve the information directly from the service.

Here's a blog with someone showing how to do this:[Call wcf service from Json](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html)

Comment: It seems to indicate in the comments that you can only call an IIS-hosted WCF service, not a Windows Service-hosted WCF service.

Comment: You can definitely consume a self-hosted service using javascript. The service needs to have the appropriate attributes but there should be no requirement to change the actual code. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792208/self-hosting-wcf-for-ajax-client or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebApp.aspx or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/2c3dc15a-b019-480c-82a5-b85765dcd761